# cannot display image in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, image, lamp

here's my code for image display -

```
$username = "xxxxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxxx";
$host = "000.001.000.000";
$database = "xxxxxxxx";

@mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die("Can not connect to database:         ".mysql_error());
@mysql_select_db($database) or die("Can not select the database: ".mysql_error());
$query = mysql_query("SELECT mimetype, Image FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$content = $row['Image'];
header('Content-type: image/jpg');
echo $content;
```

This is the error i'm getting

The image “http://www....” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

what is wrong? The datatype of field in mysql is mediumblob

Comment: How big is the image file? Is it being encoded (eg. mysql_escape_chars?) before being added to the DB?

Comment: are you sure the image you are displaying is a jpeg? you are fetching mimetype and image, but not using mimetype - which tells me you are likely going to have more than one file type stored.(gif/jpg/png and so on)

Comment: Comment out the `header()` bit and check the page again for errors. And take out those error suppressors.

Comment: the database, table and columns are utf8??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, first test, to see what is happening:

```
$username = "xxxxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxxx";
$host = "000.001.000.000";
$database = "xxxxxxxx";

if( !mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) )
  die( 'Unable to connect to Server: '.mysql_error() );
if( !mysql_select_db($database) )
  die( 'Can not select the Database: '.mysql_error() );

$query = mysql_query( "SELECT mimetype, Image FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1" );

if( !$query )
  die( 'Query Failed: '.mysql_error() );
if( mysql_num_rows( $query )==0 )
  die( 'Query Returned No Records' );

$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump( $row );
echo '</pre>';
```

That should either show you the results from the database, or an error message. If you see an error message, correct whatever is causing it...

After the above just returns the Database row contents:

```
$username = "xxxxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxxx";
$host = "000.001.000.000";
$database = "xxxxxxxx";

if( !mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) )
  die( 'Unable to connect to Server: '.mysql_error() );
if( !mysql_select_db($database) )
  die( 'Can not select the Database: '.mysql_error() );

$query = mysql_query( "SELECT mimetype, Image FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1" );

if( !$query )
  die( 'Query Failed: '.mysql_error() );
if( mysql_num_rows( $query )==0 )
  die( 'Query Returned No Records' );

$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);

header( 'Content-type: '.$row['mimetype'] );
echo $row['Image'];
```

(assuming that the `mimetype` field is something like "image/jpg")

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest adding a content-length header before your output:

```
header("Content-length: " . strlen($content))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to change the header to make it dynamic depend on the image mime-type:

```
header('Content-type: '.$row['mimetype']);
```